# posh-git shows long branch-name

Tags: git, powershell, windows-7, posh-git

I love git in my windows pwershell using posh-git. For a long time my shell used to look like this:

```
D:\repos\project [master]>
```

But now I updated from git 1.8.x to 1.9.4.msysgit.0 and the output changed:

```
D:\repos\project [master...origin/master]>
```

I love changes but this is too much and too long. How can I change the behaviour to my favourite old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled `posh-git` and this brought the old behaviour back.